# NSUrl swift 2 with greek and other special characters

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurl

I'm trying to make a server request with

`NSUrl(string: "http://example.com/α")`

In which `α` is a greek character. So when i request this i get an error and my app crashes. So i tried to encode the url to this

```
let myUrl = NSURL(string: myLink.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!
```

and now my link has become `http://example.com/%CE%B1`

where `%CE%B1` is the `α` character. Although my server does not recognise it and it doesnt send me back the data.
I use node.js with io.socket connections. Is there any way with `swift` to send the correct url without the percent encoding?

Comment: Have you read this question [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037806/nsurlstring-fullurl-returns-error/38037922#38037922)

Comment: @Nirav it still sends the request as `%CE%B1`

Comment: You need to change your server implementation to understand the letter. AFAIK, you can't send special character without percent encoding.

Comment: I think @ldindu is correct you need to change your server implementation.

Comment: @ldindu yes you are correct.

Comment: @Nirav could you tell me how to make the opossite? from  `%CE%B1` to `α` ??

Comment: I don't know how to decode this on server side?

Comment: @Nirav not on server side, but with swift in my project.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios I am posting answer for encoding and decoding check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For encode `α` in your url

```
let str = "α"
let url = str.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Now decode url string like this

```
let orgStr = url?.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
print(orgStr)
```